# How can I check if my JSON field is defined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, typescript

I am parsing JSON and trying to access one of its fields, which is an array.

```
const myObj: MyObj = JSON.parse(myJson);
console.log(myObj.myArray); //SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
console.log(myObj.myArray == 'undefined'); //SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
console.log(myObj.myArray.length); //TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
console.log(myObj.myArray !== null); //true
```

I have no problem iterating through my array and doing what I need with the data.  But I need to check to make sure the `myArray` field is valid being iterating through it.  When I try to do this, I get an error as shown above.

I am very very confused.  Can anyone explain to me what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Could you make a running example? Including (part of) the json

Comment: Doesn’t look like your json is valid, making any subsequent operation pointless.

Comment: what does `console.log(typeof myObj)` returns ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator to check whether a property is specified in an object prototype chain:

```js
const myJson = '{"a": 2}';
const myObj = JSON.parse(myJson);

console.log('myArray' in myObj); // false
console.log('a' in myObj); // true
```

Alternatively, you can check whether the field is not `undefined` (if it is, it does not exist in the object returned by `JSON.parse`), and the safest way of doing this is by using the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator:

```js
const myJson = '{"a": 2}';
const myObj = JSON.parse(myJson);

console.log(typeof myObj.myArray !== 'undefined'); // false
console.log(typeof myObj.a !== 'undefined'); // true
```

A direct comparison against `undefined` (e.g., `myObj.myArray !== undefined`) should be avoided because `undefined` can be [overridden or shadowed](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undefined).

**EDIT**: As @OliveNi pointed out, the usage of the `in` operator is dangerous because it goes through the entire prototype chain. For a safer check (as an alternative to `undefined` check), you can use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) as exemplified in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141364/how-can-i-check-if-my-json-field-is-defined/60141697#60141697).

Comment: Be careful with `in`. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Be careful while using `in`, as it searches the entire prototype chain.

```js
const myJson = '{"a": 2}';
const myObj = JSON.parse(myJson);

console.log('constructor' in myObj); // true (BAD)
```

Instead, try using `.hasOwnProperty()`, like so:

```js
const myJson = '{"a": 2}';
const myObj = JSON.parse(myJson);

console.log(myObj.hasOwnProperty("a")); // true
console.log(myObj.hasOwnProperty("constructor")); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about existence, you can simply check

`if (myObj.myArray) {`

If you want to confirm existence and confirm it's an array

`if (myObj.myArray && Array.isArray(myObj.myArray) {`

Answer (score 1):

You can check few things to verify that passed input is valid or not.

- check for the data type : If type is already an object then no need to parse it again.
- check for the truthy, i.e. `if(myObj.myArray) { }`
- Looks like myJSON is returning an empty array. i.e. `[]`

Hence, when trying to parse `[]` it returns `""` and giving the below error.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

```js
var myObj = JSON.parse([]);

console.log(myObj.myArray);
```